# Enable notification with React-Native-Notification on Android

Tags: android, react-native, amazon-sns, react-native-notifications

I'm following [this](https://wix.github.io/react-native-notifications/docs/installation-android) to enable notifications on my android device. I can see the messages getting pushed to the device through logging inside `Notifications.events().registerNotificationReceivedForeground(...)`. However, I'm not seeing any notifications popping up on the device, and on my device's notification settings, my app that i started with "npm run android" shows "This app does not send notifications"

Is it that I need to create a channel like [this doc](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels) mentioned? I did the `createNotificationChannel` function to my `MainApplication.java`, but it doesn't seem to do anything. My notification json is sent with `{"notification": {"title": "test title", "body": "test body", "android_channel_id": "..."}`

What am I missing to enable the app to send notifications? Thank you!

Comment: Are you testing this on real device or emulator?